# How to Hide Google Map if longitude and latitude are not found in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, google-maps

I am fetching google maps using coordinates i.e. longitude and latitude but the problem is when the latitude and longitude are not correct or null the div of google maps remain which I want to hide .
Can anyone help me in this ? Using Laravel 8

Comment: can't you create a blade template and just use `@if(...)`?

Comment: i am using jquery to initialize my function

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class to the div that hides it using @if on blade.

```
<div class="map @if(...) hide @endif">
```

Something like that.